# In Mysql, Left/right join gets result same column twice

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, right-join

I have a very basic problem in mySQL query. My code is that

```
select * 
from member 
left join cupwinner 
on member.mid=cupwinner.mid;
```

As a result, my final table has twice "mid" column. Table has these columns:

```
MID, name, Mtype, Debt, MID, Year, Description.
```

But i want this table by not using member.mid, name, mtype, debt, year, description.

```
MID, Name, Mtype, Debt, Year, Description
```

Is there any solution?
By the way, sorry for my English.

Comment: Why don't you want to explicitly type the columns you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule it is best to list all the columns you want explicitly in the `select`.  But, you can use this short-cut:

```
Select *
From member m left join
     cupwinner cw
     using (mid);
```